# Regex to match character x times at the start of string but don't match at all if it's more than that

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently facing the problem that I want to match a character (%) x times but not more than that at the start of a line.
My initial thought was to do this:

```
^%{1,6}
```

but this matches `%%%%%%`%

Is there a way to not make it match at all if the maximum is reached?

Comment: You need `^%{1,6}(?!%)`, see https://regex101.com/r/s5aY7F/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you! I'm new to RegEx and this was helpful. If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```cs
^%{1,6}(?!%)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%25%7B1%2C6%7D%28%3F!%25%29&i=%25%0D%0A%25%25%0D%0A%25%25%25%0D%0A%25%25%25%25%0D%0A%25%25%25%25%25%0D%0A%25%25%25%25%25%25%0D%0A%25%25%25%25%25%25%25&o=m).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `%{1,6}` - one to six occurrences of a `%` char
- `(?!%)` - a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match if there is a `%` char immediately on the right.